# Magento API error --- SoapHeaderException: Procedure 'login' not present

Tags: soap

I am lost.  I do not even know where to begin.  This is the error I am getting:

Procedure 'login' not present
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Procedure 'login' not present

Source Error:

Line 375:                service.Url = account.APIURL;
Line 376:
Line 377:                string sessionId = service.login(account.APIUser, account.APIPassword);
Line 378:
Line 379:                var orders = service.salesOrderList(sessionId, InitialiseSOAPOrderCriteria(account.TriggerOrderStatus));

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\UAT.SFSystem\Settings\ChannelHeader.ascx.cs    Line: 377

Stack Trace:

[SoapHeaderException: Procedure 'login' not present]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +1772421
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +345
   Adapters.MagentoSOAP.MagentoSOAP.MagentoService.login(String username, String apiKey) in C:\Work\WebCatch\SF\StoreFeeder\Middlewares\SFMWMagento\Adapters.MagentoSOAP\Web References\MagentoSOAP\Reference.cs:663
   Settings_ChannelHeader.magentoTestConnection(String channelGuid) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\UAT.SFSystem\Settings\ChannelHeader.ascx.cs:377
   Settings_ChannelHeader.btnTestConnection_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\UAT.SFSystem\Settings\ChannelHeader.ascx.cs:154
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while using the v2 magento api, but problem resolved when I switched back to v1 soap api of magento